# Protege 5: How can I infer a class membership of an individual through its data properties?

Tags: rdf, owl, protege, pellet

I've made an ontology in Protégé 5 using OWL/XML syntax. I have included a class Cerveza and another class Color among others. Under Color, I have 3 subclasess: Claro (pale), Medio (medium) and Oscuro (dark):

[image: Classes]

I made a data property called EBC xsd:int, which domain is class Cerveza:

[image: Data property]

So I made a restriction to class Claro to have maximum 12 EBC degrees:

[image: Class restriction]

Then I create an individual called kk and I assert the property EBC=10:

[image]

I started reasoner Pellet, and it is inferring that, as kk has EBC kk has to belong to class Cerveza. But I was expecting somehow to infer that kk belongs to Class Color / Subclass claro.

What is wrong in this design?

Comment: there is a difference in saying "maximum 12 EBC degrees" vs "maximum degree of 12" - that what you did wrong in your ontology `EBC max 12 int` means "maximum 12 EBC degrees", but your data `KK EBC 10` means "KK has EBC degree of value 12"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing *datatype restrictions* ([7.5](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-syntax/#Datatype_Restrictions)) and *data property cardinality restrictions* ([8.5](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-syntax/#Data_Property_Cardinality_Restrictions)).

Instead of:

```
Class: Claro
  SubClassOf: EBC max 12 xsd:int
```

you should write:

```
Class: Claro
  EquivalentTo: EBC some xsd:int[<= 12]
```

Comment: Thanks Stanislav. And how should I do an interval? I wrote:

Class: Medio
  EquivalentTo: EBC some xsd:int[> 12] and xsd:int[<= 47] 

Class: Oscuro
  EquivalentTo: EBC some xsd:int[> 47]

But it's getting cofused. I get individuals above 12 in both classes.

Comment: `EBC some xsd:int[> 12, < 47]`

Comment: Thanks again, but I'm still getting in Medio (EBC some xsd:int[> 12, < 47]) an individual with EBC "80"˄˄xsd:int

Comment: Is `EBC` a functional property?

Comment: I mean, does this individual has two values for the`EBC` property?

Comment: No, it has only one value. But as soon as I ticked the functional characteristics, it started working properly. Now I have what I need. Problem solved. Thanks